# Exchange online : How to list the authorized senders of a distribution group (smart way)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm looking to list the authorized senders of a distribution group
here's my code:

```
(Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "mydistributiongroup").AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom|get-mailcontact|Select-Object -Property DisplayName,Name,PrimarySmtpAddress
```

problem :
there are exchange mailboxes in my list in addition to external mail

how to modify my code to take into account the mail exchange (get-mailbox instead of get-mail contact) in a smart way and fast

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "mydistributiongroup").AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom |
Get-Recipient |
Select-Object -Property DisplayName,Name,PrimarySmtpAddress
```

I believe this will do what you want.